# Angular UI-Grid (new one) - Dynamic/Autosize Height Based on Rows

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

How do I get the angular ui-grid ([the new one](http://ui-grid.info/)) to resize based on the number of rows? Bonus question, up to a max height or maximum number of rows to show?

Answer (score 4):

Here is complete dynamic UI-Grid Implementation.

Working with pagination options and grouping.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
enableFiltering: true,
paginationPageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 100, 500],
paginationPageSize: 10,
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  $scope.gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor($scope.singleFilter, 200);
  $scope.gridApi.treeBase.on.rowExpanded(null, function(row) {
    updatePagination(row.treeNode.children.length);
  });
  $scope.gridApi.treeBase.on.rowCollapsed(null, function(row) {
    updatePagination(-row.treeNode.children.length);
  });
}

};
```

And the functions:

```
function updatePagination(rowsDifference) {
  //updating pagination will trigger singleFilter where the height is being reset
  $scope.gridOptions.paginationPageSizes = [$scope.gridOptions.paginationPageSize + rowsDifference, 25, 50, 100, 500];
  $scope.gridOptions.paginationPageSize = $scope.gridOptions.paginationPageSize + rowsDifference;
}
//you can name the function anything, I was doing global external filtering inside this, so just named this.
$scope.singleFilter = function(renderableRows) {
    $timeout(function() {
      var newHeight = ($scope.gridApi.grid.getVisibleRowCount() * 30) + 145;
      angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('grid')[0]).css('height', newHeight + 'px');
    }, 10);
    return renderableRows;
  }
```

Don't forget to inject `'ui.grid.grouping', 'ui.grid.autoResize', 'ui.grid.pagination'` dependencies

HTML

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-grouping></div>
```

[Working PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/qviCbQ6fOMpeU6uVl4su?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is not perfect but it might give you an idea.

```
  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
      reSize(data.length);
    });

  var reSize = function (rows) {
    // This will adjust the css after the Data is loaded
    var newHeight =(rows*30)+60;
    angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('grid')[0]).css('height', newHeight + 'px');

  };
```

After the Data is loaded function reSize(data.length) is triggered with the amount of loaded rows.

In reSize() I simply expect a row to be 30px in height and add an extra offset for headers and borders (which is wild guesswork here).

Look at this 
[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/7DSL9lmUTIOvLeOVaUYq?p=preview) to see it in motion.

Comment: This is good if you don't have to be able to support dynamic rowHeights.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same problem and solved it by adding an event handler to the rowExpandedBeforeStateChanged event which updates the expandableRowHeight of your gridOptions (see [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.expandable.api:PublicApi#events_rowexpandedbeforestatechanged)).

Example:

```
let gridOptions = 
{
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    data: myData,
    // ... other option fields
};

gridOptions.onRegisterApi = (gridApi) => 
{       
      gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedBeforeStateChanged(this.$scope, (row) => 
      {
              if(!row.isExpanded) 
              {
                gridApi.expandable.collapseAllRows()
                row.grid.options.expandableRowHeight = myData.length * 30 // put your length here
              }
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the expandable row height dynamic and it is expnading as per the rows that are in the child grid. I am using the external pagination option for the expandable and parent grid as well. May be I could be wrong on this topic or the bubg reported. but using the expandedRowHeight I was able to set the dynamic height for the expandable grid.

I set the expandedRowHeight like this and it works for my requirement .
This is set once the event is called to set that data as per the pagination

`

```
gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize) {
                            subgridpaginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
                            subgridpaginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
                            prepareData()
                        });`
```

```

```
if (angular.isDefined($scope.childRow.entity.subGridOptions.data)) {
                rows = $scope.childRow.entity.subGridOptions.data.length;
            }

            if (rows != undefined) {
                $scope.childRow.expandedRowHeight = 90 + ((rows) * 30);
            }
```

```

Answer (score -1):

**To set Manual Height for UI-Grid Based on Rows**
If no solution works try this one,
call gridHeight() Function from your registered onRegisterApi or watchcollection on particular array that's keep on changing.

```
function gridHeight() {
    //timeout function is used due to late updation of $scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows()
    $timeout(function () {
        // 40: header height
        // 30: height for each row


        const visibleRowHeight = 40 + (30 * $scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows().length);
        if (visibleRowHeight > 280) {
            vm.totalHeight = 280;
        }

        else {
            vm.totalHeight = visibleRowHeight;
        }
        //Adjust your height max and min accordingly like i did

    }, 200);
}
```

View:

```
<div id="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-selection ng-style="{height: vm.totalHeight+'px'}"></div>
```